# Accessing database from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, windows-services, connection-string

I have this ASP.NET app, in which I use Entity Framework to connect to the DB. Inside this app I have a class which provides different operations on the DB (add, remove etc). Everything works dandy. Now I needed to create a Windows Service which once a week updates the DB with info gathered from a repository. I thought that I could add my ASP.NET dll as a reference to my windows service, so that I could use the operations I defined there. But I get the following error:

*The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid*

I read in some other thread that I should copy the connect string to the app.config, but I don't have any app.config file in my windows service project. How can I use the EDM operations I defined in the class in both the ASP app and the windows service?

Comment: I wouldn't create a Windows Service for a task only needed once a week - Services are for running 24/7. Just create a console app and schedule a weekly task. As for the connection: Just add a `App.config` to your console app containing the same connection string as your web app (see bhuvin's answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dude u need to create an `app.config` in that case . `Copy the connection string in the web app to the app.config with the same name.` See when the windows service is running and the EF tries to create data context it doesnt find any and hence it shows the error. So u should add one app.config file and add the `connectionstring` to it appropriately.